# A issue of a variable regarding to refreshing table view

Tags: ios, global-variables, pull-to-refresh

I have a tableview  using ODRefreshControll. And i have a uislider which is in another view controller (let say myViewController) and this slider is changing a variable (let say myVariable) of tableview. The main issue is if i change myVariable from myViewController with slider and refresh the tableview, myVariable turns its initial value. I will provide my code but it is a little bit mess code, so please ask anything you do not understand from code.
Here is my code:

```
 At myTableView.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ODRefreshControl.h"
@interface myTableView : UITableViewController  

-(void)gettingVariableFromMyViewController;

@end
```

At myTableView.m

```
#import "MekanListesi.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Ayarlar.h"

@interface myTableView ()
@property(strong)NSNumber *myVariable;
@end

@implementation myTableView
@synthesize myVariable;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)gettingVariableFromMyViewController{


    NSString *unsettedVariable = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] variableUniversal];

    if (!unsettedVariable) {
       unsettedVariable= @"10000000000000000";

    }


    NSNumberFormatter * NSNF= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [NSNF setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    self.myVariable=[DegmesinEllerimiz numberFromString:AlinanYariCap];

         }

- (void)dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:(ODRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    double delayInSeconds = 1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });

}
```

At myViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
- (IBAction)actionMySlider:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myVariabelLabel;
@end
```

At myViewController.m

```
#import "myViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "myTableView.h"
@interface myViewController()
@end

@implementation myViewController
@synthesize myVariableLabel;
@synthesize mySlider;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

   - (IBAction)actionMySlider:(id)sender{
    myVariableLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f",mySlider.value];
    [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setuniversalVariable:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",mySlider.value]];


    myTableView *MTV=[[myTableView alloc]init];
    [MTV gettingVariableFromMyViewController];
    [MTV.tableView reloadData];


}
```

(At appdelegate universalVariable setted as

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *universalVariable; 
@synthesize universalVariable;
```

)

note: I am coping and pasting that code from xcode and make some changes with names of methods, classes and variables due to the fact that my native language is not English, so there can be some mistakes about names of those, Please warn me if you see one of those errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you are changing a variable when a slider value is change then you want this variable to be updated in your myTableView ? . If I'm right then your `actionMySlider` method is called whenever the value of your slider is changed, then you create a new instace of your table view ? If everything is right until now, why are you creating a new instance every time you are changing the slider value ?

Comment: no, i am already calling method from tableview when slider is changed. here is my message :  `[MTV gettingVariableFromMyViewController];`. My issue is when i pull to resfresh my variable turns its initial variable. I am using a class from github for setting a pull to refresh which called  ODRefreshControll.

Comment: It's very hard to find the issue here because the code is not so relevant, which code is called when you are performing pull to refresh. Usually there are some delegates methods that are called in this case and maybe the table view delegate/datasource delegates are called.

Comment: are they any alternative way to refresh my tableview? i know after ios 6.0 they made a pull to refresh at Xcode but i prefer my pull to refresh to be enable at other iOS versions.

Comment: The problem is not the pull to refresh, the problem is in your code that somewhere you are setting the wrong value for your variable. Also  where are you setting the new value for your variable, because in `gettingVariableFromMyViewController` you are checking the value store in your app delegate so if you don't set anywhere the new value in the app delegate, the `gettingVariableFromMyViewController` will return/set the same value @"10000000000000000".

Comment: thank you. with your warning i noticed my error in my code. can you write last comment as an answer?

Comment: Done, I added my last comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the pull to refresh, the problem is in your code that somewhere you are setting the wrong value for your variable. Also where are you setting the new value for your variable, because in gettingVariableFromMyViewController you are checking the value store in your app delegate so if you don't set anywhere the new value in the app delegate, the gettingVariableFromMyViewController will return/set the same value @"10000000000000000